# How to clear JSON Object after Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core web application, one of my pages has a sequence of steps that it performs to call stored procedures.  Depending on whether or not stored procedures return rows, I route to one of two controller actions (either rendering a partial including an additional input, or overriding what that input would do and just coming back to the page on the next step).

Right now I've got code that is nearly there.  My controller actions navigate and process correctly and my Ajax works... Sort of.

Button in the Razor view that calls the Ajax function

```
<input type="button" value="Run Check" onclick="runCheck('@actionItem.StepID', '@Model.Client.DatabaseConnectionString', '@Model.Client.ClientID')" />
```

Ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function runCheck(x, y, z) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ProcessFeedbackHasRows", "Client")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { stepId: x, databaseConnectionString: y, clientId: z },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    alert('true');
                    var stepId = x;
                    var databaseConnectionString = y;
                    var clientId = z;
                    var url = '@Url.Action("ViewProcessingFeedBackPartial", "Client")';
                    $("#processingFeedbackPartialDiv").load(url, { stepId, databaseConnectionString, clientId },
                        function () {
                            $("#confirmButton").removeAttr("style");
                        });
                } else {
                    alert('false');
                    var newUrl = '@Url.Action("Processing", "Client")';
                    window.location = newUrl;
                }
            }
        });
};
</script>
```

Controller Action

```
public JsonResult ProcessFeedbackHasRows(int StepId, string DatabaseConnectionString, int ClientID)
    {
        bool hasRows = true;
        FeedbackDetails feedbackDetails = new FeedbackDetails();

        feedbackDetails.Data = _clientProcessingService.GetProcessingFeedbackDetails(StepId, DatabaseConnectionString);
        if (feedbackDetails.Data.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            _clientProcessingService.RunProcessStepConfirmation(DatabaseConnectionString, StepId, ClientID, "No information returned, automatically proceeding to next step.");
            hasRows = false;
        }

        return new JsonResult (new { HasRows = hasRows });
    }
```

The alerts are there to just prove that the right condition was in fact met and that the right things are happening.  And this is where my problems lie.  When I had the Network traffic tab of the F12 tools open, I noticed that whatever json object is created first determines all future runs of the code.

For example: let's say I forced the first item to come through with at least 1 row returned, I'd see the alert `true`, see the JSON object in the Network tab contain `true` and see my partial view, as expected.

[image]

The next several steps would produce a a false result because no rows were returned from the SP in the controller.  The bool in the controller would be set to false, the JSON object in the Network tab would say `HasRows = false`, but my alert would show `true` and the partial still renders asking me for confirmation.  So despite not returning any rows and producing a `false` result, I see the alert `true` and the partial is rendered even though in my Network tab I see

[image]

The opposite is true as well.  If I had the first item through create an object where `HasRows = false`, and the next several would have been true, subsequent steps return true in the Network tab, but alert false and go through the `false` logic in the Ajax.

What is the best way to handle this?  Is there a way to clear the JSON or something?  I figured by creating a new JsonResult at the end of every method call, it would produce a new result to inspect, but it seems to continue using the first one sent in despite being able to see the others in the Network tab.

**What I've tried**

- Disabling cache in Ajax by adding `cache: false,` right above the URL in the `$.ajax` setup.
- Resetting the json object within the function after my `else` braces

  - `result = [];` and `delete result.hasRows;`

Despite these attempts, the ajax will always alert and go through whatever logic flow was sent first while the actual object contains the correct variable.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the problem, but it sounds like you may just need to set `cache: false` in the AJAX settings

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Excellent suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work.  It's so strange because clearly in the inspecting tools I can see that the JSON result is different, but it continues to go with whatever the first step produces.

Comment: Ok, so, what causes multiple requests to occur? you've shown us a function, but not what calls it. It sounds like a problem related to your iteration logic, but we'd need to see that to know for sure.

Comment: @KevinB Edited the question with what calls it.  I actually found a "solution" to my issue, but the overall question of how to clear this object still stands because I'm trying to get a better understanding of how all of this stuff works.

Comment: The code looks weird. `if (result)` statement returns `true` whenever `result` contains non empty string and even with `{hasRows: false}` it's not empty and result is `true`. You have to parse result as json and then check its `hasRows` property.
`var json = JSON.parse(result);
if(json.hasRows)`

Comment: Have you confirmed (before calling your ajax request) that x y and z contain what you expect them to on multiple iterations?

Comment: @KevinB Through alerts, yes. Also, when the controller actions are hit the values are all present.  Check my answer to see how I handled this, but also note that my initial question still stands because I want to gain a firm understanding of this stuff.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, check my answer.  I arrived at a similar solution but whether or not how I handled it is the correct way is still what I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this because in my inexperience with javascript and jQuery, I didn't understand exactly how the logic was being handled since I can't very easily debug the javascript the way I can the C#.

Through trial and error and alerts, I found that essentially, the  in my Ajax I had to change the `if` condition to inspect `result.hasRows` rather than just the `result`.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function runCheck(x, y, z) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("ProcessFeedbackHasRows", "Client")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { stepId: x, databaseConnectionString: y, clientId: z },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.hasRows) {
                    alert('result = true');
                    alert('result.hasRows = ' + result.hasRows);
                    var stepId = x;
                    var databaseConnectionString = y;
                    var clientId = z;
                    var url = '@Url.Action("ViewProcessingFeedBackPartial", "Client")';
                    $("#processingFeedbackPartialDiv").load(url, { stepId, databaseConnectionString, clientId },
                        function () {
                            $("#confirmButton").removeAttr("style");
                        });
                } else {
                    alert('result = false');
                    alert('result.hasRows = ' + result.hasRows);
                    var newUrl = '@Url.Action("Processing", "Client")';
                    window.location = newUrl;
                }
            }
        });
};
</script>
```

**The initial question still stands though.  Assuming I wanted to delete the entire JSON object and use my initial logic present in the question, how can I clear or delete the entire object so that every time I hit that Ajax call, a new object would be inspected?  Or is that now how this works and I solved the problem correctly?**

Comment: **A debugging tip:** Press F12 to open devtools and take note of all the available tabs there. Replace alerts with console.log() and you'll see the logs in the devtools without it interrupting your code the same way alerts do. You can even go as far as adding `debugger;` statements in your code to cause a breakpoint, or add them via the sources tab. *JS debugging in a nutshell.*

Comment: Excellent tip, @KevinB thank you!  As far as the initial question, would this solution be a good practice or would there be a better way to go about solving the initial problem I had?

Comment: That solution looks fine, I was under the impression you had a case where you were getting false negatives, not the other way around. I misinterpreted the question.